# Does closing accounts lower one's credit score?

Tags: credit-score, credit, fico-score

Does closing accounts lower or increase one's credit score, or does it depend?

Comment: Is there an immediate reason that you're worried about your score? If not, do what makes sense for you and the score will take care of itself.

Comment: Related: [Is it ever a good idea to close credit cards?](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/64491/10997)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean closing credit card accounts it will hurt your credit score in two ways:

1) It will reduce your available credit, which in turn will increase the utilization percentage of your credit if you owe a balance on any other card.

2) It will reduce the average age of your open accounts unless it was the last card you obtained.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that closing your accounts could affect a negative credit score.  If one does not have some credit card history, they assign a lower score to your ratings. I have problems because I don't have any large purchases that I am paying down.

It is okay to just keep your accounts at a zero balance.

Comment: Yes, but it's safer to close the account so someone can't make fraudulent transactions with it.

Comment: They will mark the accounts inactive if you carry a zero balance for a long time which has a similar effect to closing it.

Comment: @JohnFx Yes, I've experienced even closed accounts still being charged/credited; what's closing even for, then?